# POS price updation and stock managemnt

Tags: php, logic, billing, inventory, point-of-sale

I am working on a POS and Inventory Management Web Application and am facing an issue in updating the price list.

When there is a change in the price of a product. I want to update the price in the database but this price change must not affect the old stock of the same product already in the store am looking for a logic to handle this.

How can I differentiate the old stock and the new stock with the updated price?

Comment: maybe the best way is create a versioning for your product. which stores the products detail including it's price, and every time you receive new stock just add a version for every product

Comment: it makes trouble while generating the sales reports and also it will be annoying if a price of a product changes frequently

Comment: that's why a versioning is solution because what you will put in your report is the specific version of product which is it will not be affected if you added a new stock  of existing product with different price, because the new stock will be an another version of that product or another detail